# queries of multiple slices from a column family row in cassandra - is it possible?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

Assuming a following column family:

```
CREATE TABLE points (
    shard       varchar,
    series      varchar,
    time        timestamp,
    value       varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (shard, series, time)
);
```

I would like to execute a following query:

```
select * from points where shard=? and series in (?,...,?) and time <? and time >?
```

Or a version explicitly specifying time by a `in` clause. Under Cassandra 1.2 I get

```
Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY part series cannot be restricted by IN relation
```

I experimented with splitting `series` column into an explicit composite key and filtering on non-first part of composite column, but to no avail. Is it possible in most current Cassandra or using Thrift API?